# Idiomatic text munging in Clojure

Tags: clojure

In getting accustomed to Clojure syntax, I wrote the following `stutter` function:

```
(defn doublelist [coll]
  (flatten (map (fn [x] [x x]) coll)))

(defn stutter [s]
  (clojure.string/join
    " " (doublelist (clojure.string/split s #" "))))
```

This duplicates every word in an input string:

```
(stutter "how are you?")
"how how are are you? you?"
```

The `doublelist` function bugs me. It seems that repeating items in a list should be possible without a call to `flatten`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `mapcat` to omit `flatten`:

```
user> (defn doublelist [coll]
        (mapcat #(repeat 2 %) coll))
#'user/doublelist
user> (doublelist [:a :b :c :d])
(:a :a :b :b :c :c :d :d)
```